# Using dplyr to make a dataframe look like output from ftable -- assigning a value to certain elements using group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

Say for instance I have the following tall dataframe `df`:

```
state <- state.abb[1:10]
county <- letters[1:10]
zipcode <- sample(1000:9999, 5)

library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(CJ(state, county, zipcode))
colnames(df) <- c("state", "county", "zip")
df[1:15,]

   state county  zip
1     AK      a 2847
2     AK      a 2913
3     AK      a 3886
4     AK      a 6551
5     AK      a 8447
6     AK      b 2847
7     AK      b 2913
8     AK      b 3886
9     AK      b 6551
10    AK      b 8447
11    AK      c 2847
12    AK      c 2913
13    AK      c 3886
14    AK      c 6551
15    AK      c 8447
```

For purposes of presentation, it might look nicer like this:

```
   state county  zip
1     AK      a 2847
2               2913
3               3886
4               6551
5               8447
6             b 2847
7               2913
8               3886
9               6551
10              8447
11            c 2847
12              2913
13              3886
14              6551
15              8447
```

I use `dplyr` frequently to create crosstabs instead of using base R's `table` or `ftable` functions so that I can pipe the output into `xtable` to make a nice HTML presentation.

To make this look like output from `ftable`, I want to set all elements but the first unique one from each of the columns I grouped by to `""`. I know I can use `group_by` to perform similar operations as this using `dplyr`, but it doesn't seem to play nice with indices, which is the only method I'm envisioning to accomplish this task:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- group_by(df, state, county)
df[-1,] <- ""
```

Should I be thinking about this differently, or is there some handy `dplyr` syntax to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way. First, group the data by `state`. Any duplicated county will be `""` in the first `mutate()`. Then, ungroup the data. Given the county, `a` appears at the beginning of each state, whichever rows with `a` are ones you want to keep state names. Otherwise, you want `""`. This is done in the second `mutate()`.

```
group_by(df, state) %>%
mutate(county = order_by(county, ifelse(!duplicated(county), county, ""))) %>%
ungroup() %>%
mutate(state = ifelse(county == "a", state, ""))

#   state county  zip
#1     AK      a 2429
#2               3755
#3               6108
#4               8364
#5               9577
#6             b 2429
#7               3755
#8               6108
#9               8364
#10              9577
```

In data.table, the code above could be something like these.

```
setDT(df)[, county := ifelse(!duplicated(county), county, ""), by = state][,
            state := ifelse(county == "a", state, "")]

setDT(df)[, county := ifelse(!duplicated(county), county, ""), by = state][
            county != "a", state := ""]
```